# Search for / be searching for / looking for? I don't know how to write correctly a sentence, that looks clumsy to me

Tags: sentence-construction

I was arguing:

> Some, like me, find that criteria very relevant, and for them, what signs can they search for, among open source projects, that depict a good behavior?

- be searching for?
- be looking for?
- ?

how can I write this sentence correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Search for* is simplest and what I would use. To me, the sentence seems awkward for other reasons. You might consider leaving out "like me":

> Some find that criterion very relevant. What signs can they search for, among open source projects, that depict good behavior?

Perhaps that's an improvement.

(Although *criteria* is often used in the singular, it is actually the plural and *criterion* is the correct singular. This is analogous to *taxon*/*taxa*.)